# Connect to MapR Hive via Sql Developer

Tags: hive, oracle-sqldeveloper

Has anyone tried connecting to a MapR Hive DB via Sql Developer? I searched quite a lot of posts online, but they were all about HDP or Cloudera based Hive. The organization I am working at uses MapR. I tried enabling Third Party JDBC Drivers from Tools-->Preference-->Database in Sql Developer, but "Hive" tab doesn't pop out when I restart the app. Any suggestions?

Comment: Last time I checked (1 year ago) Oracle SQL Developer supported only the Cloudera driver (JDBC type 4.0), not the drivers derived from Apache code base (JDBC type 3.0 with limited features). Try other tools instead > DBeaver, DN Visualizer free...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter, thank you for the reply. This helps a lot.